# How to make live transition in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I want to make a live transition in jQueryMobile, when I swipe left or right, it shows a new page.

I have manager to do that on click using : `$.mobile.changePage`

I have different pages in one html page like :

```
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
<div data-role="header">
     <h1>Header 2</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content">Page Two</div>
<div data-role="footer">
     <h4>Footer</h4>

</div>
```

I want to change between these pages only by swipe left or right.

here is the code added to populate pages :

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://prod.footballclub.orange.com/ofc/news?offset=0&limit=10', function(jd) {
          
     
           
        $.each(jd, function(idx, obj) {
       
        $("body").append('<div data-role="page" id="p'+(idx+4)+'"><img src="'+obj.image+'" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">     <h8> '+obj.nbView+' vues </h8>  <h4 align="middle" style="color:#E49B0F"> '+obj.title+' <h4>  <h5> '+obj.description+' </h5><div data-role="footer"> <h4>Footer</h4> </div> </div>');
    
}); 
           

          });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile provides events for **[swipeleft](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/)** and **[swiperight](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/)**. So you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function (e) {
    var dir = 'prev';
    if (e.type == 'swipeleft') {
        dir = 'next';
    }
    GoToNextPage($(this), dir);
});

function GoToNextPage($item, direction) {
    var $next;
    if (direction == 'next') {
        if ($item.next().length > 0) {
            $next = $item.next();
        } else {
            $next = $('[data-role="page"]').first();
        }
    } else {
        if ($item.prev().length > 0) {
            $next = $item.prev();
        } else {
            $next = $('[data-role="page"]').last();
        }
    }
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + $next.prop("id"), { });

}
```

On swipe you get the current page and the direction. Then in GoToNextPage() figure out which page you should navigate to.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wjfzd6op/)**

Comment: Thank's for your working example, I have a question for you, can you please show me how to add the transition " Slide" for next and Slide with reverse : true when Prev

Comment: It works for now I had to add this : ` if (direction == 'next') {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + $next.prop("id"), { transition: "slide"});
    }
    else 
    {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + $next.prop("id"), { transition: "slide", reverse: true});
    }`

Comment: @Strange90, you can do it in one line: $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + $next.prop("id"), { transition: "slide", reverse: direction == 'prev' });  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wjfzd6op/3/

Comment: thank you so much, I have another issue, I want to populate the pages from a JSON file, but i don't see the pages i'm populating, I can see them only when I swipe left, please see the code added on the edited post

Comment: @Strange90, instead of appending to the body, insert new pages after the last existing page: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wjfzd6op/4/